# values received are not the desired result

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array called `gMul` and in it are 4 arrays, i want to take the first one and all the others equal to that array shifted n times (n represents their index in the jagged array)

the last array was equal to the array before it for some reason, for example:

```
gMul[0] = new byte[] {2 , 3 , 2 , 2}
```

then the result should be

```
gMul[0] - {2 , 3 , 2 , 2}
gMul[1] - {2 , 2 , 3 , 2}
gMul[2] - {2 , 2 , 2 , 3}
gMul[3] - {3 , 2 , 2 , 2}
```

but for some reason the result I get is this:

```
gMul[0] - {2 , 3 , 2 , 2}
gMul[1] - {2 , 2 , 3 , 2}
gMul[2] - {2 , 2 , 2 , 3}
gMul[3] - {2 , 2 , 2 , 3}
```

my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < gMul.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    //shift is a function that shifts the given array one item to the right 
    //and returns an array of bytes
    byte[] shifted = shift(gMul[i - 1]); 
    gMul[i] = shifted;
}

public byte[] shift(byte[] row)
    {

        byte tmp = row[0];
        for (int i = row.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            row[(i + 1) % row.Length] = row[i];

        }
        row[1] = tmp;
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please include your implementation of ```shift()```?

Comment: included it    now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in shift algorithm. Correct algorithm is this

```
public byte[] ShiftRight(byte[] row)
{
    var newRow = new byte[row.Length];
    byte tmp = row[row.Length - 1];
    for(int i = row.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    { 
       newRow[i] = row[i - 1]; 
    }
    newRow[0] = tmp; 
    return newRow; 
}
```

Or simply use Array.Copy.

```
public byte[] ShiftRight(byte[] row)
{
    var newRow = new byte[row.Length];
    byte tmp = row[row.Length - 1];
    Array.Copy(row, 0, newRow, 1, row.Length - 1);
    newRow[0] = tmp; 
    return newRow;
}
```

Comment: No. See edit. I was fixing my answer. Slow typing on phone